# Highly composite numbers and aliquot sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the sequence of *highly composite numbers*. The *aliquot sum* of a positive integer n is the sum of all proper divisors of n, that is, all divisors of n other than n itself.

1. Will every *hcn* have a greater *aliquot sum* than all integers less than itself?

1a. If H(n) is the nth hcn, what is the asymptotic behavior of the number of integers between H(n) and H(n+1) which have a higher aliquot sum than H(n)?

(question 1a would be interesting if the answer to 1 is "yes").

2. Are there infinitely many instances of an integer being prime and the next integer highly composite? And what about instances of the integer following an hcn being prime? And are there only finitely many hcns appearing *within* twin primes (a large example: 7559,7560,7561)?

Note: This earlier post discusses, among related matters, the number of factors of the even numbers lying between twin primes. Couldn't see anything on highly composites though. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490592/what-is-notable-about-the-composite-numbers-between-twin-primes

Comment: Remind us, please, what an "aliquot sum" is?

Comment: added definition.

Comment: Numbers $n$ such that sum of proper divisors of $n$ exceeds that of all smaller numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A034090 and highly composite numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002182

Comment: Thanks. The lists on the pages you gave does indicate that the highly composite numbers area  subset of the numbers which have greater aliquot sums than all previous numbers - there is no name given to the latter set of numbers and no proof either. Maybe it is a well known result.